# React-Native iOS runtime error: Native module cannot be null... (new NativeEventEmitter)

Tags: react-native-ios, square

There are multiple questions with a similar title, but none of the answers helped me.

I get this error when I try to run [this repo](https://github.com/rahamin1/square-in-app-test) on iOS (using react-[native-square-in-app-payments](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin)):

Additional information is available [here](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-629762613).

[image]

Comment: How did you create this project? I don't see any podfile in the `ios` folder. Most likely you are missing a ton of libraries due to that.

Comment: The ultimate goal is not to fix this repo , but to fix problems that I have with my app,s repo (which I cannot share). I tried working with cocoapods and had other problems: couldn't even get the build done (now, at least, the build is working and the failure is at runtime). You can read more about what I tried in https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66. And, as far as I understand, a project can be created with cocoapods -> without an iOS file.

Comment: You do realize that some of the dynamic libraries issues are seen at runtime right?

Comment: Yes. But I think that the libraries that I need in this repo are linked with iOS... Anyway, I am open to suggestions. Do you suggest that I use cocoapods? What should I write in the podfile to fix the problem? If you can, please download the repo, fix the problem and let me know what to do.

Comment: I don’t have a solution but If I am in your place, I would recreate this using “npx react-native init” and go from there to merge your changes. From my experience, error like this happens when there are errors while importing the modules. You should be able to see these errors in js console.

Comment: This is what I did when I created this repo.